# Read buffer is zero'd out when return variable is initialised

Tags: c, initialization, posix, fuse

This is a real WTF situation... Am I going mad!?

I noticed that my FUSE read operation had started filling the buffer with zeros after I had updated my code to stop my linter complaining:

```
int cramp_read(const char* path, char* buf, size_t size, off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info* fi) {
  int res = 0;

  struct my_filep* f = get_filep(fi);
  (void)path;

  if (f) {
    switch (f->type) {
      case fd_normal:
        if (pread(f->filep, buf, size, offset) == -1) {
          res = -errno;
        }
        break;

      case fd_special:
        if (my_read(f->specialp, buf, size, offset) == -1) {
          res = -errno;
        }
        break;

      default:
        res = -EPERM;
    }
  } else {
    res = -EBADF;
  }

  return res;
}
```

That is, specifically the `pread` branch (I've yet to write `my_read`). However, debugging showed `pread` was correctly setting the buffer to the file contents... After some digging, I found the error was when I initialised my variables: that is, the `int res = 0;` seems to be causing this behaviour. If I change it back to `int res;`, it starts working again.

What's even more strange: When I leave the variable uninitialised and print it to stderr before the very last `return` -- i.e., after all the work has been done -- the `pread` fails and I get an `EPERM` error.

Could someone explain what is going on here? I've initialised my variables elsewhere, at my linter's request, and now I'm worried I've introduced a load of time bombs just waiting to be discovered!

Comment: Your original code had undefined behaviour when the result of the call to pread was not -1, so it returned the essentially random value of whatever res contained. If you initially set res to 0 the function will return 0 if the result of pread is not -1. Which seems to be not what you want to do. Maybe you might want to return the result of the pread call unless it is -1?

Comment: I'm such a moron: I just read the FUSE documentation and the implementation of read is supposed to return the number of bytes read, rather than 0 for success and `-errno` on failure.

Comment: ...which is essentially @MarkusDheus' suggestion: Thank you for that :)

Comment: The reason why you first version accidentally worked is most likely that the pread call did implicitly set the register assigned to res to its result. If you call another function (like for logging) res would've held the result of that function and therefore would not accidentally return the right value anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'm an idiot! After reading the FUSE documentation, I found that ones `read` implementation is supposed to return the number of read bytes, rather than the usual FUSE interface of 0 for success and `-errno` on failure.

The following fixed the problem, while leaving the initialisation:

```
...
if ((res = pread(f->filep, buf, size, offset)) == -1) {
...
```

(Likewise for my yet-to-be-implemented `my_read` branch.)